# Trying to find the length of each sequence for each starting value by using collatz conjecture, 1-100, and print them out next to the starting number

Tags: java

```
    class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 1;
        for (int x=1;x<4;x++) {
          int x2 = x;
          if (x%2==0) {
            x2 = x/2;
            count++;
          }
          else {
            x2 = 3*x+1;
            count++;
          }

          System.out.println(x+"-"+count);
        }
      }
    }
```

I can't understand how I'm supposed to count the length of the sequence and print each starting number 1-100 with length of sequence next to it

I tried just counting each time it does `x/2` or `3*x+1` by `count++`; but it is putting out 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 and ive been looking at examples to try to get an idea or different perspective but all of them are scanners and nothing ive seen is similar to what im trying to accomplish.'

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to count the steps by incrementing the count variable every time you performed the sequence calculation (count++;). However, this approach only counts how many times the calculation was performed, not the actual sequence length. Also, you need a while loop to perform the sequence calculation, which continues until the current value becomes 1. Inside the loop, the Collatz sequence transformation is applied separately for even and odd numbers, accurately updating the value and incrementing the step count for each transformation. In your solution the sequence calculation is performed only once for each starting value in the loop.

This should work:

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
            int count = 0;
            int x2 = x;
            while (x2 != 1) {
                if (x2 % 2 == 0) {
                    x2 = x2 / 2;
                } else {
                    x2 = 3 * x2 + 1;
                }
                count++;
            }
            int finalCount = (x == 1) ? count : count + 1;
            System.out.println(x + "-" + finalCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sorry about not responding went on vacation but thank you for helping me out!